# Drop event not firing

Tags: silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

I have a grid on which I have set AllowDrop=true.
But the problem is that it is not firing. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. This is what I've noticed:

When running Silverlight application in debug mode in IE9 (probably applies to other versions too) drag and drop is not working at all. You can see a "denied" cursor when dragging file over the browser.

But when you open an application in IE without debugger attached, dropping files suddenly works.

It could be IE setttings problem, but drag&drop works fine in Chrome, even during the debugging. And that's enough for me ;-).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it worked setting the grid's background to a value, e. g. to transparent.

I had a huge grid with a tiny TextBlock centered vertically and horizontally. Thus it seems there's no active area except the area of the tiny TextBlock.

```
<UserControl .. AllowDrop="True">
    <!-- some other xaml code -->
    <Grid AllowDrop="true" Background="Transparent">
        <!-- some other grids ... -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Have fun,
BlackTuareg